Convolutional Neural Network is getting unexpectedly high validation accuracy, what could be causing this?
I am building/optimizing a CNN for classifcation of cars from this dataset.
My baseline model is getting suprisingly high accuracy from a very simple model architecture, I am concerned there is some data leakage from not loading the data in correctly so would like some advice please.
Loading the dataset
batch_size = 16
img_size = (64, 64)

train_dataset, val_dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    label_mode='categorical',
    seed=1,
    subset='both',
    validation_split=0.2,
    image_size=img_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
)

normalization_layer = Rescaling(1./255)

train_dataset = train_dataset.map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y))
val_dataset = val_dataset.map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y))

Building the model
def baseline_model(input_shape=[64, 64, 3]):
    model = Sequential([

        # 1st Conv Layer
        Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='valid', input_shape=input_shape),
        # Pool Layer
        MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
        # 2nd Conv Layer
        Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='valid'),
        # Pool Layer
        MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
        # Flatten
        Flatten(),
        # Fully connected layer
        Dense(64, activation='relu'),
        Dense(5, activation='softmax')
    ])
    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy', Precision(name='precision'), Recall(name='recall')])
    return model

baseline_model = baseline_model()

Fitting model
history = baseline_model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    epochs=10,
    validation_data=val_dataset,
    #callbacks=[ConfusionMatrixCallback(val_dataset, class_names)]
)

plot_training_history(history)



"surprisingly high accuracy" - maybe you just did a good job.    Try re-randomizing your training, validation, and test sets to see if it's repeatable.   Or perhaps you can try another goodness measure to see if it holds up.   What would a plot of F-beta look like?
